# Uptime shows high load, but cpu is mostly idle

Tags: cpu

Since my last reboot May 1st, `uptime` shows an average CPU usage of ~4, but top and iotop are ok. Does anyone has an idea what else to check?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uptime
08:57:14 up 14 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.08, 3.84, 2.53

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ top
top - 08:58:27 up 15 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.02, 3.88, 2.64
Tasks:  70 total,   1 running,  69 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.7 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    496764 total,    89836 used,   406928 free,    12492 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free,    49792 cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3488 pi        20   0  3152 1296  916 R   1.0  0.3   0:00.25 top
   1 root      20   0  2148  720  616 S   0.3  0.1   0:00.85 init
  39 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.45 kworker/0:2
  40 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:01.64 mmcqd/0
   2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
   3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.30 ksoftirqd/0
   4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
   5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iotop
Total DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:      12.18 K/s
TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
  41 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    8.12 K/s  0.00 %  0.83 % [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
2560 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % getty 38400 tty5
   1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init [2]
   2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
   3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
   4 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0]
   5 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ pstree
init-+-cron-+-cron---sh---...
     |      `-cron---sh---...
     |-dbus-daemon
     |-6*[getty]
     |-2*[ifplugd]
     |-lighttpd---php-cgi---4*[php-cgi]
     |-ntpd
     |-python
     |-rsyslogd---3*[{rsyslogd}]
     |-sshd---sshd---sshd---bash---pstree
     |-thd
     `-udevd---2*[udevd]

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.18+ #679 PREEMPT Thu May 1 14:40:27 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          485M        92M       392M         0B        12M        52M
-/+ buffers/cache:        27M       457M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Just in case, this is the statistics for the last month:
[image: last month stats]

Comment: That sudden jump in load average in your graph is odd. Have you noticed any processes running which didn't run before that jump?

Comment: I have seen the same behaviour on my RPi after firmware and kernel upgrade. Coming from 3.10.25+ and upgrading to 3.12.18+. After this upgrade I have seen the same as akm. Load around 4 and no programs using the CPU or IO.

Comment: I've seen this when using some slow sd-cards or usb sticks

Comment: Hello palica. That's exactly what happened.  My cron job runs a system update every first day of month.  It seems to be a bug. I found a similar post in the German PPi forum: http://www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-raspbian-hohe-cpu-auslastung

Comment: It's related to the firmware: https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/issues/46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved by firmware update: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/271